# iOS app gets reset on creation of new appium session

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation, appium

I am performing following steps

1. Set capabilities and launch ABC app. By providing app path

   capabilities.setCapability("app", "/Users/changdeojadhav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ABC/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ABC.app");
    capabilities.setCapability("bundleId","com.abc.ABC-Demo");
2. Perform some actions
3. quit driver by `driver.quit()`
4. Set capabilities for Xyz app. And launch XYZ app
5. Perform some steps
6. quit driver by `driver.quit()`
7. relaunch ABC app as mentioned in step #1.
   Expected is "App ABC should retain it's state" but ABC gets reset. 
   I have launched appium with --no-reset parameter. 
   Any idea about what I am missing here 
   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is currently no solution to reopening the application after going to the home screen *without clearing the app from cache.*

In past versions of iOS/Appium, the solution was to do:

```
from appium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Remote('http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
driver.close_app()
app = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//UIAApplication/UIAWindow/UIAScrollView/UIAButton[@name="sampleApp"]')
app.click()
```

**However this currently crashes Appium**

I will update this question when I log a github issue for it.

Answer (score 0):

The Appium help page says that it only supports multiple app testing in a single test session for Android without Selendroid:

> **iOS**: Support for automating multiple apps in one session: No
>
> **Android**:Support for automating multiple apps in one session: Yes (but not when using the Selendroid backend)
>
> http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#toc_27

I'm guessing that is why you are having this issue, and it's most likely an Instruments/XCode issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to relaunch the same app without it resetting its state with Appium 1.3.1 running with Xcode 6.1 on a Mac Mini running Mavericks.  I did not try launching another app in between launches.  I'm driving the automation from C#.

```
    protected AppiumDriver GetAppiumDriver(bool forRestart = false)
    {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.SetCapability("appium-version", "1.0");
        capabilities.SetCapability("platformName", "iOS");
        capabilities.SetCapability("platformVersion", "7.1");
        capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "iPhone Simulator");
        capabilities.SetCapability("app", _appPath);
        capabilities.SetCapability("locationServicesEnabled", true);
        if (forRestart)
        {
            capabilities.SetCapability("noReset", true);
        }
        AppiumDriver driver = new AppiumDriver(_serverUrl), capabilities, new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0));
        return driver;
    }

    public void iOSMobileAppBasicUITest()
    {
        // Initially Launch the app with the noReset capability at its default value of false to ensure a clean starting point.
        _driver = GetAppiumDriver(false);

        //Shut down the app.
        _driver.Quit();

        // Launch the app again, this time with the noReset capability set to true.
        _driver = GetAppiumDriver(true);

        // Use _driver to do whatever UI automation is desired.

        // Optional: Send the app to the background so that iOS does state preservation.
        _driver.BackgroundApp(3);

        // Close the app.
        _driver.CloseApp();
        // Alternative: _driver.Quit();

        // Launch the app.
        _driver.LaunchApp();
        // Alternative: _driver = GetAppiumDriver(true);
        ...
```

Answer (score -1):

As I known, Appium by default runs in *fast reset mode*, and it tries to clear app's data when the session ends (as a result of the invocation of `quit()` in this case). If your want to keep app's data, the option `--no-reset` should work for you.

Comment: --no-reset will persist application data that is stored after clearing the app from cache. It does not simulate tapping the home button and reopening the application.